# Exception with customer membership provider

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

I work with ASP.NET MVC4 application. 
I am trying to implement my own custom membership provider, inherited from SimpleMembership provider class.

My goals:
1. Use custom NoSQL data store.
2. Support both Forms and OAuth (Facebook) authentication in a single provider.

I succeeded to implement user self-registration and forms login. Unfortunately, after the forms login, I get an exception when going to /Account/Manage URL (by clicking on user name).

The exception is in the AccountController method:

```
    public ActionResult Manage(ManageMessageId? message)
    {
        ViewBag.StatusMessage =
            message == ManageMessageId.ChangePasswordSuccess ? "Your password has been changed."
            : message == ManageMessageId.SetPasswordSuccess ? "Your password has been set."
            : message == ManageMessageId.RemoveLoginSuccess ? "The external login was removed."
            : "";


        ViewBag.HasLocalPassword = OAuthWebSecurity.HasLocalAccount(WebSecurity.GetUserId(User.Identity.Name));
        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = Url.Action("Manage");
        return View();
    }
```

User.Identity.Name received is equal to the username of the logged-in user.

Yet the call to

```
 WebSecurity.GetUserId(User.Identity.Name)
```

throws and exception:

```
System.NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code
 HResult=-2147467261
 Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
 Source=WebMatrix.WebData
 StackTrace:
   at WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity.GetUserId(String userName)
 [continue stack]
```

In the SimpleMembershipProvider, I see a method to return user ID called for OAuth users, but not for form-authenticated users.

What could be wrong with my implementation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SimpleMembershipProvider` is specifically built for usage together with Entity Framework and SQL Server. If you want to use a NoSQL store in stead, you should create your own custom MembershipProvider that inherits from the `ExtendedMembershipProvider` class and implement the methods that you need for your functionality to work. Quite a few of them can be left to throw an `UnimplementedException` without any negative effects on the rest of your application.